# SharePoint 2019: Moving documents between Site Collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell, 2019

I'm currently looking for a sneaky solution to move documents between SIte Collections. I already found a quite good looking PnP Powershell:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://intranet.customer.com/websites/SITECOLL1
Get-PnPList
Get-PnPFeature -Scope Site
$allDocs = (Get-PnPListItem -List Checklisten).FieldValues
$targetLib = "https://intranet.customer.com/sites/SITECOLL2/Checklisten"
foreach ($item in $allDocs){
Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $item.FileRef -TargetUrl ($targetLib + $item.FileLeafRef) -Force
}
```

But unfortunately I get for every document an error message like this:

> Move-PnPFile : SiteId mismatch
>   In C:\Temp\Powershell\2019\MoveDocuments.ps1:9 Zeichen:5
>   +     Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $item.FileRef -TargetUrl ($target ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Move-PnPFile], ServerException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.MoveFile

We migrated from SharePoint 2013 via detach/attach to SharePoint 2019. Now it's time to switch over to modern UI without those expensive migration tools.

Any thougths/ideas out there what I'm missing or maybe another way to achieve the goal?

Comment: I assume that the "-ServerRelativeUrl $item.FileRef" is what is failing here.  Try formatting it like you have the targetURL formatted with the URL path to the library that you are copying from.

Comment: Or switch to "SiteRelativeUrl" parameter instead! https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the script below with copy and remove way to do this. I changed a bit from your script. It works in my end properly.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url siteURL
Get-PnPList
Get-PnPFeature -Scope Site
$allDocs = (Get-PnPListItem -List Documents).FieldValues
$targetLib = "/sites/test/Library"
foreach ($item in $allDocs){
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl $item.FileRef -TargetUrl $targetLib -Force -ErrorAction Stop
Remove-PNPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $item.FileRef -Force
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thank you!